# how to apply Skip and Take on Include

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

I have a Class that Name's is `Tag` . each Tag has Some `News` , `Article` and `Poll'. I want Get All Related Post which have Tag .
to do this I use this Query :

```
 public Tag Get(string tagName, int page, int recordsPerPage = 10)
    {
        int skip = page * recordsPerPage;
        return 
            _tags.Where(tag => tag.Title.ToLower() == tagName.ToLower()).Include(row => row.Articles
            .OrderByDescending(n => n.Code).Skip(skip).Take(recordsPerPage).ToList())
            .Include(row => row.News.AsQueryable()).OrderBy(news => news.Code).Skip(skip).Take(recordsPerPage)
            .Include(row => row.Polls).OrderByDescending(poll => poll.Code).Skip(skip).Take(recordsPerPage).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

but when I run Project I getting this error :

> The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties.

Comment: You just want one tag, why are you calling Skip and Take method?

Comment: because I search by one tag and I shoud get All Related `News`,`Articlrs` with that Tag . and I don't show All Item at first Time I load 10 Record by each Page

Comment: Has this been solved? I'm having exactly the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass an expression to Include method that isn't a Property Expression, look your code

```
.Include(row => row.Articles.OrderByDescending(n => n.Code).Skip(skip).Take(recordsPerPage).ToList())


.Include(row => row.News.AsQueryable())
```

As you can see, inside include, you are calling many methods, and it is not allowed.

You must change this for that:

```
.Include(row => row.Articles)
.Include(row => row.News)
```

Let me try to improve your code, you current code is this:

```
_tags.Where(tag => tag.Title.ToLower() == tagName.ToLower()).Include(row => row.Articles
            .OrderByDescending(n => n.Code).Skip(skip).Take(recordsPerPage).ToList())
            .Include(row => row.News.AsQueryable()).OrderBy(news => news.Code).Skip(skip).Take(recordsPerPage)
            .Include(row => row.Polls).OrderByDescending(poll => poll.Code).Skip(skip).Take(recordsPerPage).FirstOrDefault();
```

Lets break-it in newlines

```
_tags.Where(tag => tag.Title.ToLower() == tagName.ToLower())
     .Include(row => row.Articles.OrderByDescending(n => n.Code).Skip(skip).Take(recordsPerPage).ToList())
     .Include(row => row.News.AsQueryable())
     .OrderBy(news => news.Code)
     .Skip(skip)
     .Take(recordsPerPage)
     .Include(row => row.Polls)
     .OrderByDescending(poll => poll.Code)
     .Skip(skip)
     .Take(recordsPerPage)
     .FirstOrDefault();
```

If you need just one Tag, you don't need to make this big method chaining, you can simplify that using this:

```
public Tag Get(string tagName, int page, int recordsPerPage = 10)
{
    return _tags.Include(tag => row.Articles).Include(tag => row.News).Include(tag => row.Polls)
         .OrderBy(tag => news.Code)
         .FirstOrDefault(tag => tag.Title.ToLower() == tagName.ToLower());
}
```

Comment: When User Clicked On a `Tag ` I should Show All Records whicth Used Thath `Tag` . And For Best Search Result I Don't Show All Search Result . I sow 10 by 10 Recirds Each a Page . And I use Skip and Take For this